# Admob ads not showing after change language

Tags: android, admob, locale, ads

Hi my android admob ads is showing in normal way but after i run this code and restart the activity the ads not showing anymore

```
Resources resources = App.getContext().getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    if (VersionUtils.isAfter24()) {
        config.setLocale(localelanguage);
    } else {
        config.locale = localelanguage;
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    }
```

Please help me i was frustrated with this bug

Comment: I was using the app ads unit id as the xml string reference, after i hard code it.... the problem is solved